# Intragalactic time dilation?

Tags: special-relativity, astrophysics, astronomy

Would the differing relative velocities of star systems orbiting in a galaxy cause each star system to experience a different timescale relative to one another? Would the effect be significant, or do star systems generally maintain neutral relative velocities, even at very long distance?

Answer (score 0):

The sun orbits the center of the galaxy at (very roughly) 1/15000 the speed of light, which means an observer motionless with respect to that center will see the speed of earth-clocks multiplied by a factor of about .9999995.

Comment: Thanks. I wasn't sure if any of the other star systems in the galaxy are moving relative to our own fast enough for any appreciable time dilation to occur.